# query mongo based on results of query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose query:

```
let rE = await cR.find({myid: "xxxxxx"});
```

now this query will return multiple results, in which I then need to query another model based off of the `rE.class_id`, which is returned through `rE`, the query above. So I do this:

```
let cla = await Cl.find({_id: rE.class_id});
```

however, that obviously doesn't work because `rE.class_id` gets returned as multiple objects, so placing `rE.class_id` just wont work. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have  you tried to use findOne instead of find?

Comment: You can do a single aggregation query with `$lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get all Cl models where _id = (classIds of models rE)
Then you can try this one:

```
let rE = await cR.find({myid: "xxxxxx"});
const classIds = rE.map(r => r.classId);
let cla = await Cl.find({_id: {$in: classIds}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = await cR.aggregagte([
  {
    '$match': {
       myid: "xxxxxx" 
    }
  },
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'rE', 
      'localField': 'authorId', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'cla'
    }
  }
]);
```